# Java code that will give remainder using only subtraction and Not Modulo

Tags: java

Here is the question. How can you give the remainder without using modulo and division. Just only only subtraction method. Here is the question.

Find the remainder when one positive integer is divided by another positive integer using successive subtraction.

Input: Two positive integers A and B. Output: The Remainder of A/B

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try doing it with a pencil and paper - there's really no need to start with code. Try finding the remainder when (say) 24 is divided by 5. Keep taking 5 away from the number (so 19, then 14, then 9 etc). What do you notice? Hint: a `while` loop would be useful when you get to the actual code.

Comment: Start subtracting the numerator with the denominator till you get negative number once you get the negative number the number you where trying to subtract is the remainder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(a > b) {
  a = a-b;
}
return a;
```

Comment: I wanted to give him example with numbers and see if he could write this simple code... Really strange to see such questions in stackoverflow

Comment: I've got error in "return a;" here is my code actually together with you loop.

Comment: Why not use recursion or just calculate the subtracted number right away?

Comment: And what is recursion going to achieve that the simple while loop doesn't? Except of course making a simple problem look complicated for a beginner.